# Premature comment deletion on a non-answer exacerbating HNQ-badness; mods seem to refuse to act upon answer quality despite terrible content, again

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, standards

Again we see the HNQ issues on a 'popular' Covid question without any proper answers.

[Is there an unusual distribution of adverse events by lot number for COVID-19 vaccines?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/52964/is-there-an-unusual-distribution-of-adverse-events-by-lot-number-for-covid-19-va)

And the [comments under this 'answer'](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/52967/41728) were removed without any addressing of the serious shortcomings.

- The 'answer' *does not* address the claim in question as presented in the title of the question. The question asks for 'is there a distribution of pattern X', the non-answer leaves that track and talks about causality inferences from a database which implies that in the US there would be practically no pharmacovigilance at all. For that, we see zero reliable references, just another equally bad Skeptics:SE post.
- The answer then outright lies about worldwide deaths attributable to all doses ever given out for Pfizer 'vaccines' — **without references** — with that number allegedly being ≤5. This was disproven easily, and *with references,* by myself, and even by a mod with *another* ref that supposedly also contradicted this outrageous claim as ridiculous?
  For that I can't be sure: My own earlier comment was then removed, the lie still stands, without correction or criticism, as the mod-ref is a link I can't access. In any case, the stubborn refusal by OP to acknowledge that for tiny Norway it's own 'CDC' clearly states that just for the first 100 reported deaths after Pfizer vaccination, *official geriatric experts* ascertained that for 10 of those the relationship was indeed with high probability causal, despite all the difficulties surrounding such cases:

  > There is some uncertainty regarding the assessments, but in 10 cases a causal relationship between vaccination and death was considered to be "probable".

  —  Norwegian Medicines Agency: Reported suspected adverse reactions to COVID- 19 vaccines as of 18.01.2022 ([link](https://legemiddelverket.no/english/covid-19-and-medicines/vaccines-against-covid-19/reported-suspected-adverse-reactions-of-covid-19-vaccines))
- This 'answer' then goes on to misrepresent the [only study](https://www.nejm.org/doi/10.1056/NEJMoa2109730) quoted in it. Without any proof by means of quote — which of course is also not even possible in this case — 'answer'-OP claims that 'the death talked about' in that study would have been:

  > ***A-OP*** Even this death is not causally linked to the vaccine.

  This is patently false. Nowhere in that paper is this assertion to be found, neither directly nor indirectly. More to the diametrically opposed contrary, the paper explicitly states:

  > ***NEJM*** CONCLUSIONS
  > The incidence of myocarditis, although low, increased after the receipt of the BNT162b2 vaccine, particularly after the second dose among young male recipients. […]
  >
  > This finding was suggestive of a possible causal relationship between two doses of the vaccine and the risk of myocarditis. Overall, we estimated that definite or probable cases of myocarditis occurred in the overall Israeli population at a rate of approximately 1 per 26,000 males […]

  And in describing the fatality examined in the paper (but wholesale and without evidence or even argument dismissed by A-OP):

  > ***NEJM*** One 22-year-old patient with fulminant myocarditis, including troponin T levels >250,000, died within 24 hours of diagnosis.

This 'answer' does not answer the question asked, it seriously misrepresents the one reference given in it, which is also not related to answering the question. It tries to whitewash possibly unpleasant empirical data, possible observations related to it, or possible conclusions. Not much more.

That answer doesn't even have any post-notice attached to it.

So:

In light of the abused references presented in this answer, I expect some mods to be more vigilant to insist on proper reference work being done in answers.
This non-downvoting a terrible answer isn't restricted to regular users:
Of our four mods, obviously none even downvoted this really bad answer, none added a post notice label, and it looks like none followed up the abused reference? This is terrible quality control.

- Why isn't there a post-notice added?
- Why are valid criticism comments with reference quotes removed?
- How else are users supposed to correct or improve deeply flawed answers, especially in cases like these when the HNQ-effect of 'pure popularity upvoting' *destroys* the supposed working model of 'good posts get upvotes, bad ones get downvotes'?

---

As a side-note, I repeat that it seems necessary to do this, at least: if a question tests positive for a [covid]-tag, it shall be quarantined for 14 days, until the danger of infecting the voting by HNQ superspreading subsides into calmer waters. If any such question with a positive test result is found to be lifted into the HNQ buble-voting realms, then it shall be removed from that list by mods automatically, but rather swiftly if the answers are as bad as in this case.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a single question. It is a complaint about several distinct issues.

## You don't like the HNQ.

You have repeatedly indicated that you don't like the populist nature of the Hot Networks Question List.

I don't think that there is any disagreement that HNQ distorts voting by bringing in people who don't think skeptically. It is also an important recruitment tool.

I don't think this question has progressed this issue at all.

## You don't like this answer, and you think the mods should act.

The mods don't decide which answers are correct. They don't decide what is right and wrong. They police that the minimum requirements are met: e.g. that significant claims are referenced, that the conduct is civil.

I only skimmed your arguments that the answer is *wrong* here, because this isn't the place to discuss it. The question for the mods is did it fail to meet the requirements of the site.

I have never seen an expectation/demands before that all mods would downvote every "bad" answer. I don't like that expectation, but if you want to argue it should be a policy, make a meta-question suggesting it, and the community can debate it.

## You don't know why your comments were deleted.

Your first comment was snarky (and unreferenced). The response back was snarky. The conversation went downhill from there. You were both crossing the line. I responded with a chastisement not to squabble. Another mod decided to go further and delete the comments, which makes sense to me.

How do you respond to a bad answer? Edit it to improve, if possible. If it breaks the rules, flag it. Post a better one. Downvote. Comment, without the snark, and with references if you are going to posit different facts.

## Mad Scientist points out the question's *claim* is bad.

It is a loaded question.

[I had a section here describing what I wanted to see in an answer, and pointing out why existing answers didn't cover it, but then I realised I was being hypocritical.]

## You want special handling of COVID-19 related questions.

I understand from previous chats and comments that your positions on a lot of COVID-19 related topics are often a minority position and differ from some –seen as widely-understood 'consilience positions'– of some groups of 'experts' and their opinions. (I emphasise that part of being a skeptic is being open to 'the maverick' (or scientific minority positions) who points out the Emperor is wearing no clothes, so this isn't a criticism, but mavericks need to bring some great evidence with them to be heard.)

So, I can see why you see it as a topic needing special handling. However, I don't see an argument here about why it is different to other topics. Why should COVID-19 be treated differently to Homeopathy, for example?

Comment: Your own personal mod policy vis-a-vis some, eg _my_ posts, and often quick-shot heavy-handed editing is incompatible with the depiction above.There are some great edits from your account, but you also remove referenced, relevant parts, if _you_ don't like em. // "Recruitment tool": are we seeing the results of recruiting from populist posts more populist users, which then continue to make populists votes and posts thus sending more populist posts into HNQ? That looks like a sword with two edges on the handle? Quality posts need to be on HNQ, and quality needs to be the recuitment incentive.

Comment: The 'A complained about' is off the mark, distorts its ref, makes wild claims without refs etc, see above. I don't say 'all mods should', _I observe_ that 'not even a single mod did'. Following up the ref should expose the lie, insisting on refs for wild claims (post notice &/or removal seems to be a norm; sometimes?). That's a lack of quality control, and this quality control got further diminished by removing my criticism without adequate substitute. Since comments were below a believers' post denying ecidence, thus foreseeably fruitless, a post notice and direct edit seems needed at least.

Comment: "an import recruitment tool". Did you mean "important"? I don't understand what you mean otherwise.

Comment: @Laurel: Yes. Fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of problems with the question, the answers and the comments on those. The question is problematic because the title doesn't actually match the quoted claim. In this case the mismatch is particularly problematic because the title is purely about the distribution of deaths by lot, while the actual quoted claims very clearly claim that the vaccines caused all these deaths. This is something we should have caught earlier, but it's really difficult if not impossible to change the main claim after the answers are already there.

For the quoted claim "Why is it that certain batches of Covid-19 vaccine have proven to be deadlier than others?" an answer that simply explains and cites what VAERS is would actually be sufficient according to our rules. The claim includes causality between vaccine and death, and showing that VAERS does not contain any information about causality here would be an answer. It would not be a good answer, but it would not violate our rules and there would be no justification for me to delete it or add a post notice.

I added a comment about the number of deaths mentioned in the answer. This is again a bit of a shitshow here because of the unclear question. The title was about all vaccines originally, the text clarifies that it is only about the two mRNA vaccines. The deaths cited by a mod in the comments there are for AstraZeneca. And the remainder of the disagreement is probably not reconcilable because I don't think we can all agree on when a death is clearly linked to the vaccine and when not, your comment and the responses use very different criteria here.

Our rules are only a very coarse defense against bad answers. You can write some truly terrible answers while still following the letter of the law here. But if we mods would try to act more there, it would also mean that we have to make even more judgement calls about the content of the answers. And that isn't a good solution either.

As for the deleted comments, if you strongly disagree with an answer the only robust way to oppose it is to write a competing answer. The comments get out of control very quickly here, so we tend to delete a lot of them. I try to avoid deleting comments that clearly point out an obvious flaw in an answer, but this is not always possible. Especially when the discussion gets heated, we often have to remove everything. Picking favorites would cause even more trouble in those cases.

I agree with removing this question from the HNQ, the claim is just too messy and confusing. And the answer quality is not exactly what I'd like.

Comment: HNQ/fastest gun: is quality improvement on Qs auto-subverted by quickly posting bad but popular answers, then we back off from betterment since (bad) 'effort' accumulated? Lots of Qs are from newbies, many need fixing, anyways. Here, we see a fully dishonest A, with unreferenced BS, soundly disproven with refs in deleted comments. I'd suggest that instead of 'picking one side when heated' a mod may delete an entire string, but _has_ to check validity of criticism and perhaps re-post/re-phrase the important comment content? HNQ readers don't follow up refs, I try to, and this one is egregious.

Comment: The problem with "if you strongly disagree with an answer the only robust way to oppose it is to write a competing answer" is that it's completely possible to know a valid criticism of an answer without knowing the correct answer to the question.